# How to add left and right arrows to a view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How do i go about , adding arrows (left and right) to the left and right sides of a page in a view pager. These arrows should be able to navigate to the previous and next pages (fragments). How do i go about this ?

Help is needed (In any Form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make root of layout of the activity which has ViewPager type RelativeLayout and position there 2 imageView. One in the middle on the left side of screen, 2nd on the right. Assing onClick callbacks to them and change viePager page inside of callback properly.